# Nginx + php-fpm only works with all ports open on the EC2 instance

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2, php-7.2

I have a nginx server with following config for

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

and php-fpm 7.2 www conf listening on `listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`, rest all options are defaults.

This is all on ubuntu 18.04.2 on a EC2 on aws.

If I open all ports on the EC2 i can connect to site without any issues. Having only 443 and 80 keeps throwing "504 gateway timeout"

Don't see anything in `/var/log/php7.2-fpm.log` and nginx logs just say connection timed out.

I have tried switching both php to listen on 9000 and nginx proxy pass it to 9000, instead of unix socket. Gets same behavior.

Comment: So you're getting through to Nginx, but Nginx isn't able to connect to PHP?

Comment: When i open all ports nginx can connect to php, as all request do show in nginx logs. With only 80 and 443 open it says.  `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream` and no errors on php side.

Comment: Is it possible another `location` directive is kicking in? Are you always accessing it using the same URL, just different explicit/implicit ports? A gateway timeout can also come from PHP itself, maybe try kicking up `fastcgi_read_timeout` (also maybe `send` and `connect`). Are you performing any complex logic in PHP, or have you tried accessing a very simple `echo 'hello';` script?